# What is the best way to draw out a physics question for this website?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I'll have questions that I can't describe well in words, and I was wondering if there were any recommendations for how to draw it out, such as a free download to draw with or something.

Comment: Asked on the main site as [What software programs are used to draw physics diagrams, and what are their relative merits?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401) (rightfully locked as off-topic under current site rules).

Comment: Thankyou very much!